# dask client.scatter command hanging

Tags: python, dask

I have a 4-band raster image (NAIP imagery) and another raster obtained by the scipy SLIC algorithm containing integers that indicates the segmentation on that image.

The next step in the workflow is calculate statistics for all the pixels in a segment, and there are 300,000+ segments, so I'm trying to parallelize the calculation with Dask.

I first created this function to call for each segment id:

```py
def get_features(id):
    segment_pixels = img[segments == id]
    return segment_features(segment_pixels)
```

but when I ran this using Dask bag for just a few segments:

```py
import dask.bag as db
b = db.from_sequence(segment_ids[:80], npartitions=4)
b1 = b.map(get_features).compute()
```

I could see the memory use was growing rapidly, and realized I was passing the two rasters (`img` and `segments`) data to each job, which of course is a terrible pattern.

I read about how `client.scatter()` can be used to pass objects to the workers in situations like this, so tried this:

```py
scattered_img = client.scatter(img, broadcast=True)
scattered_segments = client.scatter(segments, broadcast=True)

def get_features(id, img=scattered_img, segments=scattered_segments):
    segment_pixels = img[segments == id]
    return segment_features(segment_pixels)
    
b1 = b.map(get_features).compute()
```

but this crashes my session, so what am I doing wrong?

Here is the [whole reproducible notebook](https://nbviewer.org/gist/rsignell-usgs/811a70296584922153410fe31b5d04e6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly pass the scattered objects into the `map` call so that dask knows to include them as dependencies in the graph. So change the last line to:

```py
b1 = b.map(get_features, img=scattered_img, segments=scattered_segments).compute()
```

As @mdurant suggested in the comments it is better not to include the defaults in the function signature. So update your function definition to:

```py
def get_features(id, img=None, segments=None):
    segment_pixels = img[segments == id]
    return segment_features(segment_pixels)
```

Comment: Also good *not* to include them as defaults in the signature, as you don't want them serialised along with the function defenition closure.

Comment: Yes good call I will update.

Comment: Woohoo!  This worked great @jsignell and @mdurant!   See cells [31] and [32] in this now functioning notebook: https://nbviewer.org/gist/rsignell-usgs/03b82f3133f98e9cec318867ee8b4971